# How to update Kit Assembly extension table fields after releasing Kit Assembly?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

IN Kit Assembly screen, once i release Kit Assembly then i can never update INKitAssembly,

But I have to allow KitAssembly Extension table fields to update. how may i allow to update custom fields added in INRegister(InKitAssembly) extension table?

Is there a way to update InKitAssembly extension table fields on Release operation completion, DO you have any call back delegate after Release kitAssembly long operation completion?

Comment: What types of fields are you looking to update? simple fields when released, or calculations?

Comment: It's about updating a custom field located in a INRegister DAC extension. The solution is to re-enable the fields in RowSelected event and in worst case to disable the automation steps which disables the fields. There are similar questions, general guidelines like setting AllowUpdate=true can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004556/how-to-enable-a-custom-field-on-gl301000-when-the-batch-is-posted/46963349#46963349

Comment: Another answer on the same subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436074/7376238

Comment: This related answer focus on automation steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450281/7376238

Comment: Same topic again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45177649/7376238

Comment: Thanks @Hugues sir for help, In case of "Kit Assembly", when i update after release i got the error Serial Number 'SRF000' for item 'ABC001' is already received. any comment on it?

Comment: What do you mean by update? This happens when you call an update method?

Comment: Update means, when call save method.
when call Base.Document.Update(inRegObj);
then call Base.Persist() method.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your extension values in the INReleaseProcess persist should work. Something like this:

```
public class INReleaseProcessExte : PXGraphExtension<INReleaseProcess>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void Persist(Action del)
    {
        foreach (INTran row in Base.intranselect.Cache.Updated)
        {
            if (row?.DocType != INDocType.Production || row.Released != true)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // update your extension here
            var inTranExt = PXCache<INTran>.GetExtension<INTranMyExtension>(row);
            inTranExt.MyField = "X";
            Base.intranselect.Update(row);
        }

        del?.Invoke();
    }
}
```